# Why does MAMP not change the php version

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp

I just went from windows to mac and am now trying to import my local wordpress projects from xampp to mamp. I have some issues with my websites and I suspect it is because of the newer version of PHP that MAMP uses.

In the preferences MAMP offers "7.1.0" and "7.0.13" but when I change to the older version and click "save", MAMP restarts the servers and when I check the settings it is back to "7.1.0".

How can you fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to change the PHP Settings after changing the available PHP versions that MAMP offers. I did this by going to "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php" and renaming one of the folders, for example adding "_X" at the end. By renaming the folder of one of the 2 available PHP versions you remove it from the selection. Afterwards I was able to change and save the standard PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

A bug was recently submitted on [Mamp's Bugbase](http://bugs.mamp.info/view.php?id=5815#) but it is unresolved at this moment. Meanwhile, the solution described by koedev, as well as the solutions found at the workaround cited by Arda Kazanci could be used. 
Globally, two different solutions are available in the workaround cited by Kazanci: The koedev solution, that is, adding a _X in folder's name, and a second one that seems to be more professional, that is, adding an "extra" folder to httpd.conf and "selecting" inside which php versions should be used by mamp. Because some users didn't succeed in making work the extra configuration of httpd, it may be faster and simplest to follow the koedev solution.